# Jar file is not showing in maven dependencies After clean install

Tags: java, maven

I am using STS for my project, It is not showing the jar file after clean and install, instead it is showing the folder instead of jar file. I tried everything but not able to figure it out.

Note: The Jar is present in .m2 folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A jar file does not contain dependencies only the code your own project.

Comment: @khmarbaise: The jar file downloding from repository and showing the same jar in .m2 folder but not in Spring tool suite under project Maven Dependencies